# Threading in Python or PHP is 100 times slower on my 2018 18 core iMac

Tags: php, python, multithreading, macos, pthreads

I have several python and PHP multi-threading scripts running on an old 2015 Mac el capitain OS with 4 cores that take only a few minutes each to complete.

Bought a 2018 18 core iMac pro running high Sierra and now those same scripts take 40 hours EACH to complete. Any hints what I can due to solve this problem? Anyone else, threading with php or python on high Sierra or an iMac pro?

Really dumbfounded right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called apple and they said to wipe the system completely clean with a new install of the MAC OS system because the issue could be due to a conflict in software. I did that and it did fix the issue. So I will have to step through all my software installations to identify the one conflicting with the threading.